# Spring Data JPA with ManyToOne save operation is throwing org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I'm experimenting  with Spring Data JPA but having issues with saving ManyToOne relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;


 @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 private Address homeAddress;

 protected Customer() {}
 // getters and setters ...
}
```

Many customers can have the same address :

```
 @Entity
 public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String postalCode;
  private String city;
  private String line1;
  private String line2;
  private String country;

  public Address() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  // getters and setter 
}
```

CustomerRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>       {

List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
List<Customer> findByHomeAddress(Address address);

}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {



        Address address1 = new Address("07093", "Brooklyn", "129 67th st", null, "USA");
        Address address2 = new Address("03333", "Qeeens", "333 67th st", null, "USA");
        // save a couple of customers
        Customer jack = new Customer("Jack", "Bauer");

        jack.setHomeAddress(address1);
        repository.save(jack);                  
        repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian",address1));

 }
}
```

So I tried to save two customers with the same address I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: hello.Address; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: hello.Address
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:299) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at hello.Application.lambda$0(Application.java:35) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
... 6 common frames omitted
```

How can I resolve this issue? you see full code at [this git location](https://github.com/suleimana/spring-data-jpa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the other side of relationship, make it bidirectional.
In `Address` class,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "homeAddress", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Customer> customers
```

**EDIT**: The above suggestion not fix the problem.
Your problem made me curious, and I checked it in my local.
As you're running these operations each on their transaction, the entity manager detaches the saved `address1` after the first save(entity manager/session is closed after every repository interaction).

Your method would work if for example you would wrap all operations inside one Transaction which keeps entity manager open(which is normally done on service, depending on your rollback logic)
I tested with the below code and it works.

```
    package hello;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    public class CustomerService {
        @Autowired
        private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

        @Transactional
        public void store(){
            Address address1 = new Address("07093", "Brooklyn", "129 67th st", null, "USA");
            Address address2 = new Address("03333", "Qeeens", "333 67th st", null, "USA");
            // save a couple of customers
            Customer jack = new Customer("Jack", "Bauer");

            jack.setHomeAddress(address1);

            customerRepository.save(jack);                  
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian", address1));
        }
    }
```

Also, I had to remove the *naryana* starter from pom.xml

Comment: Im getting the same exception. in addition, I want a solution where I can keep it unidirectional.

Comment: In my opinion all seems to be correct. Can you provide the source code to run some tests?

Comment: @simas_ch See the full code at [this git location]( https://github.com/suleimana/spring-data-jpa)

Comment: The problem ist the line new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian",address1)

Comment: The reference to address1 is after the save of jack in the wrong state. When having many-to-one you should save the to-one separately like Abdullah suggested

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with my many to many problem, thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130

Answer (score 1):

Persist your addresses first using `addressRepository` and then refer to it.

Try this

```
Address address1 = new Address("07093", "Brooklyn", "129 67th st", null, "USA");
Address address2 = new Address("03333", "Qeeens", "333 67th st", null, "USA");
address1 = addressRepository.save(address1); 
address2 = addressRepository.save(address2);

// save a couple of customers
Customer jack = new Customer("Jack", "Bauer");
jack.setHomeAddress(address1);
repository.save(jack);                  
repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian",address1));
```

PS : I have not tested this but this should work.

Comment: this solution worked as well but I had to change cascade=CascadeType.MERGE .

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with my many to many problem, thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130

Answer (score 0):

So this is q summary of what actually worked for me:

1- using CustomerRepository and AddressRepository as @Abdullah Wasi suggested. this one worked as long I have cascade=CascadeType.MERGE as a cascade type:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private Address homeAddress;
```

2- using CustomerRepository and execute the operation from a service with @Transactional as per @isah answer. The option also worked as as long I have cascade=CascadeType.ALL as a cascade type:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private Address homeAddress;
```

the service

```
  package hello;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomerService {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void store(){
        Address address1 = new Address("07093", "Brooklyn", "129 67th st", null, "USA");
        Address address2 = new Address("03333", "Qeeens", "333 67th st", null, "USA");
        // save a couple of customers
        Customer jack = new Customer("Jack", "Bauer");

        jack.setHomeAddress(address1);

        customerRepository.save(jack);                  
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian", address1));
    }
}
```

I consider @isah as more optimal solution, since my operation will end up  in service class.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with my many to many problem, thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130